# How to store request body in GridFS using Restify server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lodash, gridfs, restify

Cannot save file larger than pipe chunk size (~64K).

Using mongodb 3.4.0, Relevant node dependencies

- restify 4.2.0
- mongodb ^2.2.12
- lodash 4.16.6

  ```
  bookeeppingData = {request, id, ...meta}
  clone = lodash.cloneDeep(bookkeepingData)

  const {
      request: req,
      id: _id,
      meta: metadata,
  } = clone

  const bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(                                                                                                                                                      
      db,                                                                                                                                                                               
      {bucketName: 'my_gridfs_collection'}                                                                                                                                                          
  );                                                                                                                                                                                    

  const uploadSteam = bucket.openUploadStreamWithId(                                                                                                                                    
      _id,                                                                                                                                                                              
      undefined,                                                                                                                                                                        
      {metadata}                                                                                                                                                                        
  );                                                                                                                                                                                    

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {                                                                                                                                                        
      console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);                                                                                                                         
  });                                                                                                                                                                                   

  req.on('end', () => {                                                                                                                                                              
      console.log('There will be no more data.');                                                                                                                                       
  });                                                                                                                                                                                   

  req.on('error', (e) => {                                                                                                                                                           
      console.log('req on error', e);                                                                                                                                                   
  });                                                                                                                                                  

  uploadSteam.on('finish', function() {                                                                                                                                                 
      console.log('finsish');
      keepThebooks(bookkeepingData);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  });   

  uploadSteam.on('error', (e) => {                                                                                                                                                      
      console.log('uploadstream on error', e);                                                                                                                                          
  });                                                                                                                                                                                   

  req.pipe(uploadSteam);
  ```

  }

When sending a file smaller than the ~64K, The console output is

```
Received 57259 bytes of data.
There will be no more data.
finish
```

This is the corresponding curl --verbose output (minus the json response):

```
*   Trying ::1...                                                                                                                                                                             
* TCP_NODELAY set                                                                                                                                                                             
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8060 (#0)                                                                                                                                                 
* Server auth using Basic with user 'driver'                                                                                                                                                  
> POST /artifact?branch=xyz&role=PHOTO&where.lat=55&where.long=77.2&where.acc=12&sys=system&id=1234&sys=system2&id=1234b&created=2018-11-01T18:41:50.850Z&tz=-600 HTTP/1.1                    
> Host: localhost:8060                                                                                                                                                                        
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxx                                                                                                                                                   
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1                                                                                                                                                                     
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: image/png
> Content-Length: 57259
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 388
< Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 20:58:16 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

When sending a file larger than ~64K, the console output is:

```
Received 65536 bytes of data.
```

(That's it -- no error)

The corresponding curl --verbose output is:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8060 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'driver'
> POST /artifact?branch=xyz&role=PHOTO&where.lat=55&where.long=77.2&where.acc=12&sys=system&id=1234&sys=system2&id=1234b&created=2018-11-01T18:41:50.850Z&tz=-600 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8060
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: image/png
> Content-Length: 84801
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I expected this to work, and for the console to be something like:

```
Received 65536 bytes of data.
Received 19274 bytes of data.
There will be no more data.
finish
```

Comment: The real problem wasn't discernible from original post (sorry about that).  Prior to passing the request (a stream) to the code below, I was using lodash.cloneDeep on an object that contained the stream as a field. (lodash 4.16.6). Updating code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on the same team.
Turns out we were deep cloning the object containing the stream. When we stopped cloning the entire file uploads fine.

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer... Please refrain from adding comments in an answer.